# Slick.js smooth transition between first and last elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm trying to create a sliding gallery using [Slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) - look at the "Center Mode" part.

All in all the gallery functions correctly, however I have a small glitch: when I'm on the last element and scrolling to the first - I'm not getting a smooth transition, but rather a small jump of the first element.

I created a Codepen to demonstrate what I'm talking about: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLExjo

I tried to modify any possible class or classes combination:

```
.slick-cloned, .slick-active etc...
```

But I'm still getting this jump. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slick has a somewhat strange behaviour regarding classes that it adds to or removes from elements "on the edges" of the slideshow. One approach to fix that problem is to add an event handler and fix the classes by yourself:

```
$('.your-selector').slick({
    // configuration
}).on('beforeChange', (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) => {
    if (currentSlide !== nextSlide) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.slick-center + .slick-cloned').forEach((next) => {
            // timeout required or Slick will overwrite the classes
            setTimeout(() => next.classList.add('slick-current', 'slick-center'));
        });
    }
});
```

Essentially, it will enforce the next (or previous) element in the slideshow to actually have the `slick-center` class that you set the transition on.

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRyXrG for a demo.

Comment: Wow, that surely is an unexpected behavior! Thank you so very much, it worked great!

Comment: This saved me a lot of trouble! Good day sir ! Have an upvote !

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I'm having the same issue, and didn't find. Anything that helped , so I did a little brute force, is not the ultimate fix, because has a small delay but at least all animations are the same now.

I use Angular but should work for others, I will explain globally

1. Declare a variable in a place were you could have access to it from `beforeChange` and `AfterChange`. I named it `previousSlide` type `number` in my case.
2. In the `beforeChange` function assigned the `event.currentSlide` to my `previousSlide.
3. Now In the `afterChange` function I have both informations my variable `previousSlide` and this function's variable `event.currentSlide`
4. Then I create mi custom animation here and make all the transitions etc.etcin previous and current slides .

Test it and now from last to first (and viceversa) is the same as the other animations

Note: what I am animating is only some styles in the slides, so the active slide change some colors and height and the slide that leaves the center transitions back to the normal style, so don't know about some bigger transformations behavior. Also using Slick's CenterMode